# Linux container for desktop experience

Tags: linux, desktop-environment, desktop, container

Just out of curiosity, are there any cases of it being possible to have a Linux container *be* the user-facing desktop environment instead of it being interacted with via the command line or any "remote desktop" connection? In this manner, it wouldn't be like a virtual machine where the "guest" is a window inside a "wider" environment/host.

Answer (score 0):

flatpak, snap and appimage packages *are* Linux containers. So, deploying end-user applications that are directly used from within your desktop environment is quite normal – no command line handling involved.

So yes, that exists, and you're quite possibly using applications that way – for example, Ubuntu's firefox is a snap package (and because canonical did the integration a bit half-assedly, you notice the looser integration when compared to better-working native firefox on similar platforms); if you ask Fedora's Software Center to install software, for some packages, you can choose whether to use the flatpak or the native version, you can install e.g. the Signal desktop client as flatpak and launch it as if it was natively installed, and so on.

So, not only does this exist, it's so mainstream that you might not even have noticed you're already using it.

Comment: That has nothing to do with my question. I am speaking of entire OS environments running in containers.

Comment: @Melab exists; as said, Ubuntu is moving towards complete parts of its user-facing software being snaps; the whole Android distribution of Linux (since at least version 10) uses Linux namespaces for file system access of *any* app, including your app launcher / desktop environment, which *is* what makes linux containers. Qubes, NixOS and other use different isolation technologies (not containers). You will generally find that there is need for a central component that "interworks" the different things running on your machine, which hence needs a more "native" access to the machine; on …

Comment: "the usual" Linux desktop environments like Gnome, XFCE, KDE…, that has to be the DE, and anything else is free to run in containers (again, Ubuntu does this for a lot already, and on fedora you can achieve it if you want to); but to move even the DE into a container needs a more radical rework of the Unix permission system, and that's why Android is different to all other Linux distros. Hope this helps!